# Is master-master replication equal to two-way replication?

Tags: database, replication, database-replication

Can we say that master-master replication is equal too two-way replication and one-way replication too master-slave replication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well yes, a master is read-write while a slave is, at best, read-only.

If you are allowing writes on both servers, you have to make sure they share the same data, but also the same locks to keep data integrity and consistency.